# LEFT JOIN and WHERE causing error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a nested mysql_query.

```
$resultSub = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM ensembles 
                           WHERE en_name = $name 
                       LEFT JOIN ensemble_names on ensembles.en_name = ensemble_names.en_nm_ID 
                       LEFT JOIN students on ensembles.en_stu = students.s_ID 
                       LEFT JOIN part_names on ensembles.en_part = part_names.p_nm_ID 
                        ORDER BY $sort $orderBy");
```

The query works fine without the WHERE clause, which I thought may be filtering out rows for the `LEFT JOIN` command, but that's not the case.

Comment: Your where clause should come after the joins.

Answer (score 9):

The WHERE clause should be placed after the LEFT JOINs:

```
$resultSub = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM ensembles 
                       LEFT JOIN ensemble_names on ensembles.en_name = ensemble_names.en_nm_ID 
                       LEFT JOIN students on ensembles.en_stu = students.s_ID 
                       LEFT JOIN part_names on ensembles.en_part = part_names.p_nm_ID 
                           WHERE en_name = $name 
                        ORDER BY $sort $orderBy");
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies Damn that was quick.

Comment: I had copied the text after reformatting.  You beat me to it +1

Comment: I was actually in the middle of elaborating on the original answer, doing pretty much what you did. +1 Karma point to you.

Comment: I had to beat you at *something* :)

Comment: Got it.  Through some trial and error I found the same solution.  I wasn't aware of the order required.  I see now where to learn about this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you put the `WHERE` clause in the wrong place.

Read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).